# How can I sort ActiveRecord Objects by id array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

My Env.

```
ruby 2.0.0-p195
rails (4.0.0.rc1)
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1)
```

I want to sort ActiveRecord Objects by id array.
I tried with order by field.

```
ids = [1,4,2,3]
Foo.where(id: ids).order('FIELD(id, ?)', ids)
```

However it's failed.

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?}), ö, ÷, ï, ñ' at line 1:
```

Then I try

```
ids = [1,4,2,3]
Foo.where(id: ids).order('FIELD(id, #{ids.join(","))')
```

it's of course success. However I'm afraid that it may have SQL Injection risk because Array ids are generated from session value.

Is there any better and secure ways?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is stored in `a`? I think you might be looking for `Foo.where(id: ids).order('id ASC')`. See all about querying and ordering in the [Rails Guides on the ActiveRecord Query Interface](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. "a" is mistake for "ids". I edited the mistakes.

then I want to do is not "ORDER BY id ASC" but "ORDER BY FIELD(id, 1, 4, 2, 3)".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right it is a security hole.

I see two possibility:

**Convert to numbers**

```
ids = [1,4,2,3].map(&:to_i).compact
Foo.where(id: ids).order("FIELD(id, #{ids.join(',')})")
```

I think this should be secure because you ensure that values are numbers and then you remove nil entries. nil entries would be non-numbers entries.

**Escape string**

```
escaped_ids = ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize(ids.join(","))
Foo.where(id: ids).order("FIELD(id, #{escaped_ids})")
```

You just escape the content of your string... Nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this answer using the FIELD method on Rails6 but was encountering errors. However, I discovered that all one has to do is wrap the sql in `Arel.sql()`.

```
# Make sure it's a known-safe values.
user_ids = [3, 2, 1]
# Before 
users = User.where(id: user_ids).order("FIELD(id, 2, 3, 1)")
# With warning.

# After 
users = User.where(id: user_ids).order(Arel.sql("FIELD(id, 2, 3, 1)"))
# No warning
```

[1] https://medium.com/@mitsun.chieh/activerecord-relation-with-raw-sql-argument-returns-a-warning-exception-raising-8999f1b9898a